# Use multiple buttons with value, when clicked they save to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<button id="option1" onclick="b1" value=1 >1</button>
<button id="option2" onclick="b2" value=2>2</button>
<button id="option3" value= 3>3</button>
<button id="option4" value= 4 >4</button>
<button id="option5" value= 5>5</button>
<button id="option6" value= 6>6</button>
<button id="revolver">shoot</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Javascript:

---

```
const array1 = [];
const doc = document; 
let health = 3;
let revy    = doc.getElementById("revolver"); 
let bullet1 = doc.getElementById("option1"); 
let bullet2 = doc.getElementById("option2");
let bullet3 = doc.getElementById("option3");
let bullet4 = doc.getElementById("option4");
let bullet5 = doc.getElementById("option5");
let bullet6 = doc.getElementById("option6");
```

what i want to do is to add a function that when clicked aka bullet1.onclick = function something.
but i dont know how to use this value later as i use `array1.push(bullet1.value)` in a function as seen under.

```
 bullet1.onclick = function(){
    array1.push(bullet1.value)
    console.log(array1) //when clicked it returns the [1] and ads every time clicked
}
console.log(array1) //returns []
```

how can i use this [1] value later? aka outside the function later? do i need a specific function or arrow function like `let b = () => {} b = "something i can use the array for"`  and use onclick in the button or`function myfunction(){} function();`

---

BTW im planning to create multiple of those functions like the one above, so i can use the last value to combat a bot i use.  ALSO this is a method i wanna try as im trying to save all the buttons values each time each of them is clicked. and then i can use it later. were gonna save all the clicks into an array. then ill use the last value in the array to combat a bot.

---

hope you understand, if you guys have any questions what i mean i can try be better at explaining

Comment: that code to work should have `array1` in global space. For example if you declared the variable using `var` outside of any function scope and outside any module. otherwise you should need to save the state inside the dom since it would be easily be retrieved from any other scope having access to it through `document`. To do something like that you get a dom element related to its domain and set its data property thorugh `element.setAttribute('data-nameofyourstate', yourvalue)` and then later from anywhere `element.getAttribute('data-nameofyourstate')`

Comment: If you want to use the variable outside your function, then declare it globally (outside your functions) and then reuse it in all other functions

Comment: @MrJami hi so if i declare it outside the functions this would mean i have to use `bullet1.onclick = array1.push(button1.value) ` right?